# How to move and resize the browser's window in Opera and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, resize, opera, move

I was looking for a way to resize and move the browser's window and I've found these:
`self.resizeTo(w, h)` and `self.moveTo(x, y)` - this seems to work perfectly, but only in Firefox and IE (tested with IE8, I don't know how it works in the previous versions).
How can I force the same behavior (resizing and moving) in Opera and Chrome? In these browsers the above solution does not work at all. Just nothing happens and **nothing** appears in the error console.

Comment: Note that resize/move may be disabled even for pop-ups on Firefox. Mucking around with window positioning is widely regarded as obnoxious and blocked for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Opera and [Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091) you can use `window.resizeTo(w,h);` but it won't affect maximized tabs (so you can only move and resize popups).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it and it doesn't work indeed, so you're right, it will probably work only in popups. That's not what I expected. Thank you anyway. If I won't get any better answer soon, I will accept your one.

Comment: @rhino: It doesn't work in IE when tabs are enabled either. You simply can't achieve what you want reliably these days.

Comment: @Tim Down: I don't know which version of IE are you talking about, but on my IE8 with tabs enabled everything works just like in Firefox - I can freely resize and move the window by using JS.

Comment: @rhino: I'm using IE 7. It works when there's only one tab but not if there's more than one.

Comment: You're right, I haven't tried it before. Indeed, if there's more than one tab, just nothing happens.

Comment: Note that Opera also has two preferences (under content - javascript preferences) named "Allow moving of windows" and "Allow resizing of windows". If these are disabled by the user there is no way the script can get around it.