# this.moveTo doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The following code works fine in Firefox and IE but it doesn't work in Google Chrome, anyone have an idea of how to make it work? or an alternate way to move a window in Google Chrome?

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Open windows for clicks</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function moveWindow()
  {
    this.resizeTo(400,300);
    this.moveTo(0,300);
  }
</script>
<body onload="moveWindow();">
  <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've asked a similar question once, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884116/how-to-move-and-resize-the-browsers-window-in-opera-and-chrome

Answer (score 7):

That's not possible because if it was it would be abused by ad-companies, hackers, designers without taste and god knows what else.

I doubt it even works in firefox, can't remember if i changed it myself but for me that code does nothing with my firefox.

You can maybe move windows you've created yourself with window.open but dont expect window.resize/move to work just by opening a website.

Comment: It does work on my firefox, maybe you tinkered with your settings. I wonder if there is a setting to allow this in Chrome as in Opera...

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's rather a bug, with number 1137420 to be precise, as the explanation of the start-maximized command line argument seems to indicate. (see ao http://www.ostreff.info/?p=1737)
Google guys need themselves a feature like that to test their browser...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveWindow()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.resizeTo(400,300);
        this.moveTo(0,300);}
    ,100);
}
</script>
```