# Javascript set browser window size

Tags: javascript, html, browser, window-resize

What is the best way to set the size of the browser window when the page loads?
I think this can be done in JavaScript. Please explain. Here is my code that is not working!

```
<html>
<body onload="window.resizeTo(640,480)">
<video src="rushmore.mp4" controls="controls">
your browser does not support the video tag
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you including some more javascript code that could be interfering ?

Comment: No! That is the whole page source. I just figured out it doesn't work in Google chrome but it does in IE.

Comment: Don't do this unless you absolutely have to, for UX's sake.

Comment: Yes I am using Google Chrome. why doesn't it work?

Comment: There is a known bug (feature ;-) it is reported here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091

Comment: Is there a way I could bypass this bug and have it work in Google Chrome?

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer - I have posted a comment as an answer as it became to long - hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put this in an answer as the comment became to long.

The only thing that I have found that is close to the resizing of the chrome window is to use a chrome extension that can resize the window.
The actual extension command is `chrome.windows.update(...)`.

Take a look [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html).

But I am not sure this is what you are looking for.
If it still interests you there are at least 2 extensions that can do this, that I have seen try [this one](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal)

Be happy and good luck!

Comment: **Why this is accepted answer:** See "**Important notes:**" in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35801906/1835470

Answer (score 16):

This should do the trick, setting the height and width to your desired dimensions.

```
window.resizeTo(500,500)
```

You could set it `onload`.

```
<body onload="window.resizeTo(500,500)">
```

Comment: I am not sure that this works in Chrome. (Only if it is a new instance of the browser)

Comment: @Julian, good point. From my experience and the following SO post it does not work in any browser with other tabs working, mainly for a popup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884116/how-to-move-and-resize-the-browsers-window-in-opera-and-chrome

Comment: I just tried it with Chrome as a stand alone window - doesn't work. There is a bug in chromium - see link in comment to question.

Comment: This assumes that you are using px (pixels?) Perhaps a percentage of the window's width and height properties to be set to 98% would do a more intuitive approach since there are such a variety of devices that could access this content.. just an idea to be shared here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130946/jquery-dynamic-height-with-window-resize