# Change width & height of APEX Page

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a an APEX page which has a button on, when they click the button it opens another page on top of the main page, I'm trying to set the width and height of this popup window. I tried the following in the 'inline' box under the CSS section in the page properties but it doesnt overrule the main CSS like it says its suppose to, can anyone see any problems with it?

```
.body{
width:200px;
height:200px;
     }
```

I dont really want to set it in the shared componants because i only need this IE window/page to be a specific size.

Will these sizes also set the size of the IE window or just the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS.
You could try to use the window.resizeTo function as seen here : [Javascript set browser window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238603/javascript-set-browser-window-size)

Edit your popup page, and add the code to the "Execute when Page Loads" section: `window.resizeTo(200,200);`

I tried this in IE8 and firefox and it works.